# NodeJS "make test" returns a Permission denied

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to test my NodeJS app using Mocha and Chai, however I'm getting this error :

```
root@xxxx-Vostro-1540 : sraperproject # make test
/bin/sh: 1: ./node_modules/.bin/mocha: Permission denied
make: *** [test] Error 126
root@xxxx-Vostro-1540 : sraperproject#
```

How am I supposed to resolve this ?
I've already done this, but in vain :

```
root@xxxx-Vostro-1540 : sraperproject # ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 oct.  23 20:37 /bin/sh -> dash
root@xxxx-Vostro-1540 : sraperproject # file /bin/sh
/bin/sh: symbolic link to `dash'
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the permissions of `sraperproject/node_modules/.bin/mocha`.

Comment: I did. Here is the result : `lrwxrwxrwx 1 occulti occulti 44 déc.  13 20:40 ./node_modules/.bin/mocha -> ../mocha/bin/mocha`